# Italy Zero Coupon Yields

Tags: interest-rates, data, historical-data, calibration, models

I am looking for historical data for Treasury bills and bond yields for Italy on a monthly or daily basis. Where can I get this data?

Comment: Possibly http://www.worldgovernmentbonds.com/country/italy/ has what you are looking for

Comment: Many thanks but they don't have an excel option.